# How can I fetch the commerce user purchase journey metrics from the GA4 API?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to fetch the following metrics appearing in the user purchase journey in the analytics API, however I am unable to find them in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

For reference the metrics are

1. Session start
   (User count)
2. View product
   (User count)
3. Add to cart
   (User count)
4. Begin checkout
   (User count)
5. Purchase
   (User count)

The close ones that I got were FirstTimePurchases for the fifth metric (which was accurate) and checkouts for the fourth. However, checkouts was not accurate since it reflects the number of events themselves, not the number of users performing the events, so the same user could have checked out twice. Any help is appreciated.